# XML - What is the difference in use and function between e.g. <person name="JohnDoe"></person> and <person>JohnDoe</person>?

Tags: xml

Ive seen the first one with multiple attributes in one bracket (e.g. `<person name="JohnDoe" age="25">`), but i dont quite understand what exactly the difference between is, and i would also simply like to know what these two kinds of objects are called (i couldnt google this question because i had no idea what their names are in the first place)

I know that both can do the same thing (which is why im asking this), but i am looking for good use cases to use either of them (e.g. using API namespaces in attributes instead of an element, putting data into elements instead of attributes)

Comment: I'd suggest reading about XML basics.

Comment: It depends entirely on the application that outputs and interprets it.

Comment: I did that and it literally said on W3 "no idea when to use what": "There are no rules about when to use attributes, and when to use child elements. My experience is that attributes are handy in HTML, but in XML you should try to avoid them. Use child elements if the information feels like data." and thats kinda confusing? I was hoping there are at least some general rule of thumbs or guidelines that are more specific than "feels like data"  -  for example, in Cisco APIs, they often use attributes for namespaces, so that might be a hint?

Comment: Both do not do the same thing at all.

Comment: Then feel free to explain that - as far as i can tell both are pretty much interchangable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

But you can't do this:

```
<foo value="<bar>baz</bar>" />
```

You can encode angle brackets using entities:

```
<foo value="&lt;bar&gt;baz&lt;/bar&gt;" />
```

But now it's just text "baz" rather than nested XML. Equivalent to this:

```
<foo>&lt;bar&gt;baz&lt;/bar&gt;</foo>
```

From the XML perspective that's the only difference I believe: you can't nest tags inside tags, but not inside attributes.

If you don't need to nest tags, both choices are valid. There is no other technical difference. XML spec doesn't have any semantic rules for using one over the other.